# How to properly prepare makefile for bigger project?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem with compiling and linking my project with directories organisation as showed below.

```
/project
|
|____/Components        (header files and source codes of all components)
|    |
|    |____/X            (header files and source codes of component)
|         |
|         |____/src     (source codes)
|         |
|         |____/include (header files)
|
|
|____/make              
|    | 
|    |____-Makefile     (Makefile)
|    |____-source.inc   (list of directories with header files)
|    |____-source.list  (list of every source file, .c and .cpp)
|
|____-main.c            (main source file)
```

When I run make in cmd, I get this error :

```
make: *** No rule to make target '../build/obj/main.o', needed by '../build/bin/app'.  Stop.
```

It is important for me to remain this directories organisation.

Here is my Makefile

```
OUTDIR = ../build/
OBJDIR = $(OUTDIR)obj/
BINDIR = $(OUTDIR)bin/

LD = g++

APP = app

INC_DIRS = $(shell cat source.inc)

CFLAGS = -g0
CXXFLAGS = -g0 -Wall
LDFLAGS = -g0

COMPILE.c = $(BUILD_VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS)) -c $< -o $@
COMPILE.cc = $(BUILD_VERBOSE)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(addprefix -I, $(INC_DIRS)) -c $< -o $@

SRCS = $(shell egrep .[ccpp]$$ source.list)
OBJS = $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)%.o,$(basename $(notdir $(SRCS))))

$(BINDIR)$(APP): prep_dirs $(OBJS)
    @printf "\nBuilding Project $@\n"
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJS) -o $@

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.c
    @printf "\nCompiling: $<\n"
    $(COMPILE.c)
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

$(OBJDIR)%.o: %.cpp
    @printf "\nCompiling: $<\n"
    $(COMPILE.cc)
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

prep_dirs:
    $(BUILD_VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OUTDIR)
    $(BUILD_VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
    $(BUILD_VERBOSE)mkdir -p $(BINDIR)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @printf "Cleaning executables...\n"
    $(BUILD_VERBOSE)rm -rf $(BINDIR)*.exe

.PHONY: cleanall
cleanall:
    @printf "Cleaning all objects...\n"
    $(BUILD_VERBOSE)rm -rf $(OUTDIR)
```

source.inc and source.list

```
source.inc
../Components/X/include

source.list
../Components/X/src/some_source.c
../main.c
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I fix it and left main.c in the same place?

Comment: I personally stopped to write makefiles in favour of higher level build systems like cmake. Much better option

Comment: *"How to properly prepare makefile for bigger project?"* - By not doing it. Use manually written makefiles for small projects and not for big.

Comment: Did you consider using other build automation systems, such as [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) ?

Comment: It is always difficult to correctly write Makefiles when the source and/or target files are not in the current directory. In your case `make` doesn't know that `../main.c` is supposed to be the source for `../build/obj/main.o` and doesn't find a rule that would build the .o file from an existing source file. The same for `some_source.c`. Maybe `VPATH` or `vpath` can help. You would have to specify `..` and `../Components/X/src` as directories to search. This can lead to ambiguities if you have files with the same name in different source directories.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Ninja was designed to be used by higher level build systems or generators. Replacing `make` with `ninja` will probably not help much here. See https://ninja-build.org/

Comment: @Bodo He might've really meant Meson, which uses Ninja under-the-hood - in which case, I second the recommendation to use Meson instead of `make`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general:
Not sure exactly what your problem is, but this is what I do. The project has a single global object directory (OBJDIR). Every source directory has its own Makefile, which looks like this:

```
# list of sources in *this* directory
CCSRC = a.cc b.cc etc 
OBJS := $(addsuffix .o,  $(CCSRC))
VPATH = $(OBJDIR)
 .SUFFIXES: .cc .o
 .cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

The project top level has a Makefile, which simply changes into each src directory and runs make in that directory:

```
include $(PROJ_HOME)/top.mk

# this allows sub-makes to find out if they have been invoked from this
# top-level make, or from a local make (from emacs in a source file directory,
# for example).
CALLED_FROM_TOP = true
export CALLED_FROM_TOP
    
all :
        cd dir1/src;          $(MAKE)
        cd dir2/rtv;          $(MAKE) debug=$(debug) etc
```

'top.mk' includes global defines, exports, whatever.

It's hard work, but gives you infinitely better fine-grained control than any build system I know about.